# Haverá um bug na atribuição de chapéus?

Tags: bug

Hoje, quando entrei no site, verifiquei que me foi atribuído o chapéu  **Bûche de Noël**, que é obtido ao *"perguntar, responder ou votar em 25 de Dezembro"*.
No entanto, não votei, respondi ou perguntei nada hoje(até agora).

O mesmo aconteceu no dia 24/12, quando entrei tinha recebido o chapéu **I Have A Little Dreidel**. Na altura fiquei em dúvida porque não tinha a certeza se tinha tido algum tipo de participação na véspera, depois da meia-noite.

Como voltou a acontecer fui verificar, foram estas as minhas últimas participação nos referidos dias:

- Análise em **2016-12-23 22:15:32Z**
- Análise em **2016-12-24 17:31:19**

Há algo que me está a escapar ou foram-me atribuídos os chapéus indevidamente?

Comment: Foi um bug... e pelos vistos já está corrigido. Mais aqui: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288735/224030

Comment: @Sergio entendi que é by-design - o bug seria a não entrega do chapeu, que não é o que o ramaral descreveu.

Comment: @bfavaretto tens razão... li demasiado rápido.

Comment: @Sergio Pelo que entendi a data para atribuição não é UTC nem local mas sim a "dos fuso horários mais a leste do mundo".